# Buttons using color from theme and not from the drawable

Tags: java, android, xml

It seems like all my button in my app are getting their color from the theme and not from the drawable that I set. in the xml to the left of the line number it displays the right color and even in the drawable it also displays the right color.

Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/LightBlue"/>
            <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/Green"/>
            <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/Green"/>
            <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

XML (I only added one button to save space)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/AntiqueWhite"
    tools:context=".SecondScreen">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton_top"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from `Button` to `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton`

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton_top"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```